# Java Stack Sort

Tags: java, sorting, stack

In this program I have to open a file and print it to a textArea then make sure all the parenthesis, brackets, etc. match up.  Then I print out in another textArea if the parenthesis are matched up.  My questions are as follows:  Do I read from the file or from the first textArea?  Do I create the stack in the Actionlistener or in the constructor?

Comment: try both, compare rather than waiting for an answer

Comment: Your second question is going to be hard to answer without more information about your code.  Which constructor?  What action is the ActionListener listening for?

Comment: Could you give a code snippet, where you print from a file to a textArea?

Comment: I'm guessing the best answer is in the hover-over text here - http://xkcd.com/1185/

Answer (score 0):

> Do I read from the file or from the first textArea?

I'd read from the first TextArea.  When dealing with file I/O, it's best to read from the file and close it as soon as you can.  If you've already read the contents of the file into memory, you might as well use the copy you already have.  That will be faster than reading the file again.

> Do I create the stack in the Actionlistener or in the constructor?

This is kind of hard to answer without more information about how your code is structured.  In general, I'd create a data structure in the narrowest scope that it's needed.  If you only need the stack for one operation, just create it in the method where it's needed. (This sounds like what you're doing.  I think you only need the stack to check that brackets are matched, so you probably want to create it in the narrow scope of your ActionListner.)